# Booking availability check using SQL

Tags: sql, date, exists

I have an SQL table with several records.
The user will give a from date (pick up), a todate (drop off) and the vehicle ID.

The ideal query is to go through the records and check if the specific VehicleID on those dates is booked. Note that the bookings have status. If the status is "Pending" or "Confirmed" it should consider it a booked/not available.
On the otherhand, if the status is "Cancelled" or there are no records for that VehicleID on the given dates, it should be considered as free/available to book.

I have asked this question before when the query had not too many arguments but, after adding these arguments I am completely lost.

Here is my sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b794c1/2/0

And here is the query which it seems to return false data:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN y.BookingID IS NOT NULL THEN '0' 
    ELSE '1' 
  END availability 
FROM (SELECT 1)x 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_bookings y 
    ON FromDate <= '2021-12-22' 
    AND ToDate > '2021-12-15' 
    AND VehicleID='1009' 
    AND Status !='Pending' 
    AND Status !='Confirmed'
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM tbl_bookings
         WHERE VehicleId = '1009'
           AND Status IN ('Pending', 'Confirmed')
           AND FromDate <= :to_date AND ToDate >= :from_date
       ) availability
```

`EXISTS` returns `1` for `true` or `0` for `false`.

If for the vehicle with id `'1009'` exists a row in the table with status either `'Pending'` or `'Confirmed'` and `FromDate` before (or equal) to the passed *drop off* date **and** `ToDate` after (or equal) to the passed *pick up date*, this means that the vehicle is booked and `EXISTS` will return `1` and finally `NOT EXISTS` will return `0`, which will be the availability of the vehicle.

Here, it is important to compare `FromDate` to `:to_date` and `ToDate` to `:from_date` and not the other way around, so that all cases for the date intervals are covered.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=2881107d6ace2476b63c2f48bc986d71).

Comment: Thanks @forpas! Your query seems to work. Could you please give me a brief description of the logic behind your query. I have a picture since SQL is quite readable. But I would like to confirm. Thank again for your time and effort.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks a lot @forpas. Detailed answer!